# How do you access Webmin?

Tags: linux, webmin, virtualmin

I've installed webmin on linux,

Now how do you use it?

Oh yeah before you mark my question down, webmin documentation wiki is offline. So obviously I would have rtfm first....

Comment: You might want to consider changing your question to "How do you access Webmin?" as that seems to be what you accepted as an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access webmin with a web browser http://youripaddress:10000

Comment: HD - What is the default username + password?

Comment: user root, password = the same as your root user

Answer (score 10):

Webmin is a web based application so you need to access it through your browser. It usually runs on port 10000, so the URL is usually:

```
https://servername:10000
```

Once you have logged in with a valid user you should, if it was setup correctly, be able to control many of your servers services from the web interface.

The default user name and password is that of your root user.

Answer (score 7):

In some distro, like Ubuntu, the root user is locked. This means that you can't use root to login in webdmin, unless you unlock it and set a password for it (I don't advise to do that).

I faced this issue and this is what I did to fix:

1. `sudo vim /etc/webmin/webmin.acl`

   Copy the line root: acl adsl-client ajaxterm apache ...longlist... to a new line. Then replace root with a the name of an existing Linux user.
2. `sudo vim /etc/webmin/miniserv.users`

   as before, copy the root entry to a new line and replace root with the username specified in step 1.
3. `sudo service webmin restart`

   restart webmin
4. `https://servername:10000`

Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have webmin STARTED (usually /etc/webmin/start) you should be able to access it here:

http://www.yourdomain.com:10000 (or whatever port you specifified during install)

Username: root
Password: yourPassword

Here is the online documentation for webmin:

http://webmin.com/docs.html

And yes, looks like its not responding but I figured I'd provide the link anyway so that future people coming here can find it easily.

Once you're done looking at Webmin, be sure to take a look at Virtualmin as well.

Comment: Note (for future readers) that Webmin also supports the sudoers file; any users that have ALL permissions (i.e. they can become root at will on the command line) will be allowed to login to Webmin and have full access. This handles the case of Ubuntu and other distros that don't have a root password, by default, but the first user has sudo privileges.